# Right way to convert dates to UTC

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

my apologies if this question doesn't make much sense, but I'm new(ish) to Actionscript, and was wondering if you could help me solving this problem.

I'm building an application that given a time-zone, tells you what time in that location it is. It works great when I'm working with locations where the timezone is GMT (UTC), but fauils miserably if the timezone on the host machine is anything else, as it will still add the time to the host machine regardless.

So I was thinking what I have to do, is convert the machine time, into UTC (using getUTCDate() etc), and use that as a base. I was wondering if that's the right way to go, or if there's any better way to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

**UPDATE**
After Eugeny89's answer, I modified my code and created this method to convert the current date to UTC for me. Just wondering if that's the best way to go about it.

```
private function convertToUTC(dtDate:Date):Date{
            dtDate.setTime(dtDate.getTime() + (dtDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000))
            return dtDate;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `getTimezoneOffset()` (difference in minutes between users time and UTC time) or `getUTCHours()` of class `Date`. See [manual](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html) for more details

Comment: Nice one. that this the trick. Updated my previous post with what I've done. would you be able to give a better suggestion?

Comment: Hm, that's starange! `dtDate.getTime()` returns mileseconds, and `getTimezoneOffset()` returns minutes. I think you wanted to write `dtDate.getTimezoneOffset() / 60000` instead of `dtDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000`. But in general the method seems to be good.