# Get wrong timezoneOffset in AIR/Flex/AS3

Tags: date, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, timezone-offset

in Germany I get on my PC:

```
new Date().getTimezoneOffset(); //-60

new Date().timezoneOffset //-60
```

But as my PC shows me correctly I am in `UTC+01:00` which is the correct timezone for Berlin, Amsterdam...

How can I fix this?

Kind regards

Christian

Comment: A quick google of your problem found this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124822/right-way-to-convert-dates-to-utc

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#getTimezoneOffset()) getTimezoneOffset() returns "The minutes you need to **add** to the computer's local time value to equal UTC. If your computer's time is set later than UTC, the return value will be negative.".

So -60 IS the time you have to add to the computer's local time to get UTC when you are in the UTC+1 timezone :)

Answer (score 1):

`getTimezoneOffset()` returns the difference, in minutes, between universal time (UTC) and the computer's local time as per http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#getTimezoneOffset().

If UTC time is 3:00pm then your local time is 4:00pm. Then the difference is -60 minutes which is calculated as below:

3:00 - 4:00 = -60 mins.